# Spring beans with database properties which are also reload-able

Tags: java, database, spring, properties, code-injection

My question is basically is a followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599252/how-to-configure-a-spring-beans-with-properties-that-are-stored-in-a-database-tab),
I need Spring to inject properties to bean which are loaded from DB (this is answered in the above question) another like to be able to reload these properties. So when I change property value in the DB:

- It'll be reloaded automatically
- I can ask Spring to reload (re-inject) new values

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not contain any built-in logic which would continuously watch your database and invoke some method when data changes (which is what you have described).

You would need to implement some logic yourself to continually poll the database, detect changes, and then re-populate the beans.

Comment: @matt-b I see, how can it be done. Where should I place this logic?

Comment: In case you want to tell Spring to reload new values you could write a method and make it [manageable via JMX](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jmx.html). Whenever you trigger the reload logic you could e.g. poll the database/load a properties file that uses the new values to set your bean's properties.