# How to load properties file from property file and database at the same time in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties

i have a app.properties file,which define the database connection configuration such as

```
#dataSource
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/test?useUnicode\=true&characterEncoding\=utf-8
jdbc.username=
jdbc.password=
```

and  i place some dynamic properties in database,load by a custom implementation of `AbstractFactoryBean` ,follow this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601913

and the applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" order="1" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" order="2"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    ....
</bean>
```

`Cannot find class [${jdbc.driver}]`.

how can i make sure the  `AbstractFactoryBean` load the properties first ?

Comment: Where in your project is app.properties located?

Comment: i have move the datasource part out of the contextConfiguration and set the real jdbc url in the datasource.xml independently. thanks @ Ayub Malik.